# How to get iOS stack trace in release build?

Tags: ios, stack-trace, callstack, backtrace

（1）Some of our users said that our app sometimes does not work fluently, so how can we **get the stack trace** in order to know what happens at that moment?

（2）we want to get the stack trace like this:

> 0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000018146ad8c 0x181325000 + 1334668

it should at lease includes these elements so that we can symbolicate them: **the addresses of executable code, load address of the binary image, binary image name**.

（3）"[NSThread callStackSymbols]" can not meet the requirements.

Comment: Not work fluently or crash? When crashing the app generates a crash-report containing a stacktrace which you could retrieve via iTunes connect I think.

Comment: @TMob Not work fluently. You are right. When a crash happens, there are some ways to get the stacktrace. But there are few available ways to get a stacktrace when the app is still running. It seems that PLCrashReporter does not work well because it consumes too much CPU which causes the UI to be stuck for several seconds.